# How to create a loss function that penalizes duplicate indices in the output tensor?

Tags: loss-functions

We're working on a sequence-to-sequence problem using pytorch, and are using cross-entropy to calculate the loss when comparing the output sequence to the target sequence. This works fine and penalizes the model correctly. However, we also have the added constraint that the prediction can't contain repeated indices, e.g.

`good: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

`bad: [1, 2, 2, 4, 5]`

We would like to add an additional penalty term that *punishes* the model further for producing duplicate indices, which would be added to the cross-entropy loss.

How would I construct this additional loss function in pytorch?

PS: Yes it's true that we could just *hack* the code-generation piece to not generate duplicate indices and then incorporate this into our beam-search, but I would like to first see whether this additional constraint produces a better model!

Comment: Is your question conceptual or about the specific `pytorch` implementation? Conceptually it should be easy to do by adding a term that counts the number of repetitions.

Comment: What is your data? Why do you want to avoid repetitions?

Comment: .@Rich Doesn't the loss function need to be differentiable? In this case I need a differentiable function that counts duplicates (?) 

.@Tim the output data represents sequence token markers, that must be unique